# gcc sequential list of -L paths and -l libraries

Tags: gcc, makefile

I am looking at a `Makefile` written by someone else and I see that (after variable expansion) he calls `gcc` with a sequential list  of `-L` paths followed by `-l` libraries.

For example:

```
gcc file.o -Lpath_1 -la -lb -c -Lpath_2 -ld -le -lf ... -o binary_file
```

My questions are:

- Does this call guarantee that `gcc`:

  - **only** looks into `path1` when searching for `-la`, `-lb` and `-lc`,
  - and **only** looks into `path2` when searching for `-ld`, `-le`, and `-lf`?
- Is this "proper" (recommended) gcc syntax?

Comment: It is proper syntax for `gcc`, but very bad style for a Makefile.